# error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, builder, build-script

This is my code:
showing error in this code

```
getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
```

this is full code :

```
 public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: What you able to see in *logcat* post it.

Comment: Does this String `default_notification_channel_id` real exist in your string folder...

Comment: yes <resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyNewProject</string>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id">Supreme_CH_01</string>
</resources>

Comment: Please don't abuse the comments for posting code. Edit your question instead and add the information there.

Comment: What's your support library version?

Comment: Library Version -- v7:25.3.1

Answer (score 1):

use **Notification** instead of **NotificationCompact**
eg:

Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))

Answer (score 0):

From the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html i can see that `new NotificationCompat.Builder` take as paramater `context` and `string`, you are giving `this` and `String`, `this` referes to `com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService` not to a `context` in your case.

Comment: How did you use context ?

Comment: private Context context;           
 and (context,getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))

Comment: Yes but `context ` refere to what ?

Comment: @B.M [What is Context on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

Comment: Im asking how he is defnining `context` on his code, not the definition of `context`

Comment: @B.M The context is always the same: it is the context identifying your app. A lot of classes are extending `android.content.Context`, therefore sometime `this` is the context, other classes that don't extend Context `this` is not the context.

Comment: @Robert did i say the opposite? `FirebaseMessagingService ` does not extend `Context` im i wrong ? i think you just misunderstood what i said

Comment: [`FirebaseMessagingService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) is a `Context`. `android.content.Context` -> `android.content.ContextWrapper` -> `android.app.Service` -> `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, Google's pretty consistent with their naming, so anything with `Service` in the name is generally gonna extend `Service`, which is a `Context`. The OP's problem is likely that they're using an old version of the support library, before `Notification` channels were introduced, so there's only a constructor that takes just the `Context`.